# What asp.net event should I use?

Tags: asp.net, security, forms-authentication

I have an asp.net 3.5 app that uses forms authentication. Requests with particular referral IP address should bypass the forms challenge. What event (perhaps in http module??) is the best to hook into to implement this?

regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every request goes through event `Application_BeginRequest` in `Global.asax` so you can use your logic there.

Comment: I was about to disagree and post a new answer, then realised I was wrong. Of course its important to remember to check if they are already logged in (I'm assuming they will be auto-logged in) as well as checking their IP address. so you dont' just auto-login on every request. :)

Comment: Correct, I only want to auto login those users coming from behind the firewall by redirecting them to the integrated auth piece of the same application, which is in effect regestered as short host http name (the only way for Integrated Auth to work silently with the browser)